# getting gnome-session-b error that it fail to create dbus proxy genomeScreensaver.How to solve it?

Tags: gnome, 17.10, gnome-screensaver

Due to this error the system bootup time increases by 30 seconds. after logging It takes more 40 sec to start shell.

Kindly let me know how to solve this error.

system details:

```
Ubuntu 17.10
Env: Xorg gnome
```

Error at  gnome-session-b

```
CRITICAL: Unable to create a DBus proxy for GnomeScreensaver: Error 
calling StartServiceByName for org.gnome.ScreenSaver: 
GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.Spawn.ChildExited: Process 
org.gnome.ScreenSaver exited with status 1
```

Comment: sudo gedit /etc/gdm3/custom.conf

Comment: uncommenting the line #WaylandEnable=false

Comment: all gnome strange behaviour got solved